# Python: altering items in a list when the list is a value of a dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary, replace, list-comprehension

This may sound simple, but I can't wrap my head around it.

My dictionary:

```
MY_DICT = {
    "foo":[
        "bar/",
        "baz"
    ],
    "another_key": [
        "1_item",
        "2_item/".
    ],
}`
```

I need to remove the trailing slash from "bar" and "2_item", and put the values back into the dict.

This is what I have (and it works):

```
for key in MY_DICT:
    MY_DICT[key] = [item.rstrip('/') for item in MY_DICT[key])
```

But I'm wondering if there's a more 'pythonic' way to do this using dict/list comprehensions.

I want to remove all trailing slashes from every item in a dictionary, using dict comprehensions

Comment: Perhaps `for key, value in MY_DICT.items(): MY_DICT[key] = [elem.rstrip('/') for elem in value]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your solution is fine for modifying the dictionary in place.

If you want to create a new dictionary, you can use a dictionary comprehension with an embedded list comprehension.

```
new_dict = {key: [item.rstrip('/') for item in value] 
            for key, value in MY_DICT.items()}
```

Comment: thank you. the syntax of comprehensions is quite vexing.

Comment: The syntax of comprehensions (or generators in general) should be pretty natural to English speakers. When you have nested data like this, just do them one at a time and substitute.